# DeepStack custom model building on GPULab fails

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, yolo

I'm trying to use GPULab environment to build a custom model for DeepStack. It fails with the following error:

```
[W NNPACK.cpp:79] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "deepstack-trainer/train.py", line 530, in <module>
    train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer, wandb)
  File "deepstack-trainer/train.py", line 90, in train
    model = Model(opt.cfg or ckpt['model'].yaml, ch=3, nc=nc).to(device)  # create
  File "/home/jovyan/deepstack-trainer/models/yolo.py", line 96, in __init__
    self._initialize_biases()  # only run once
  File "/home/jovyan/deepstack-trainer/models/yolo.py", line 151, in _initialize_biases
    b[:, 4] += math.log(8 / (640 / s) ** 2)  # obj (8 objects per 640 image)
RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.
```

Looking around, people are treating the NNPACK as a warning to be dismissed, but in my case it ends with `RuntimeError: a view of a leaf Variable that requires grad is being used in an in-place operation.`. Not sure how to continue (if possible).

All project's packages in `requirements.txt` were satisfied and the environment do hold CUDA and cuDNN

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the NNPACK error (warning) is not related to the part comes after.

The real error is the second part and is due to incompatible pytorch versions as was found and stated on this [closed issue](https://github.com/johnolafenwa/deepstack-trainer/issues/10) by [@marcokloeckler](https://github.com/johnolafenwa/deepstack-trainer/issues/10#issuecomment-804744604)

running @marcokloeckler proposal:

```
pip install torch==1.7.1+cu110 torchvision==0.8.2+cu110 torchaudio==0.7.2 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```

downgrade the pytorch version on GPULab environment and allowed the project to run.